# problem of displaying attribut names when i want to search a record of a field on tryton

Tags: python, xml, tryton

i have a problem of displaying attribut names when i want to search a record of a field on tryton .it display "attribute "ID" , that i never made on my code .

This is how it looks like my code :

i coded a field

```
position_meta = fields.Many2One('meta.position', 'Position')
```

the class "meta.position":

```
class Meta_position(ModelView, ModelSQL):

    __name__ = 'meta.position'

    position = fields.Char('Position', translate=True,
        required=True)
    area = fields.Char('Area', translate=True,
        required=True)
    def get_rec_name(self, position):
        return self.position
```

on xml, i was called the field i made :

```
 <label name="position_meta"/>
 <field name="position_meta"/>
```

then i coded a file position.xml contain some records i want them to be printed when i search a record from the field :

the code was:

```
<tryton>
    <data>
        <record model="meta.position" id="meta_position_1">
            <field name="position">A</field>
            <field name="area">ar1</field>
        </record>
        <record model="meta.position" id="meta_position_2">
            <field name="position">B</field>
            <field name="area">ar2</field>
        </record>
       
      
 </data>
</tryton>
```

then i was set this file `position.xml` on `tryton.cfg`

My problem is that the field did'nt accept the name of the attributes i made like `position` or `area` from the the position.xml that i made

I want to know what's the problem

is their another step i should do it to display my own attributes.

At the bottom ,there a picture of how it looks like the field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `tree` view for `meta.position` (and better even a `form` view) otherwise trytond generate a default value which contains only the `id`.